# How do you change the app store's large icon on iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I need to change the large app icon (512x512) for app store. I can't find how to to this through iTunes Connect. I's possible change the app screenshots though. I read the [iTunes manual (page 97)](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fdocs%2FiTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf&rct=j&q=itunes%20connect%20pdf&ei=zsRgTv2xLsz1-gbg58Ef&usg=AFQjCNHIe5z2hgZca_u0YEjm4U3sU_3b-g&sig2=hil4RoykewZIZMMDwLN0kA) and it says that it can be done but I only have the "choose file" button for screenshots, not for the large icon.

I am also confused because the same manual says on on page 99 that edit-ablity of the large icon is locked.

What am I missing?

Comment: It does not work i Chrome - only Safari..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, editing of large icons that are already in use by iTunes Connect is locked, but however, You can still register a new update to Your app, in which You can upload Your new 1024*1024 icon
:)

Comment: OK, having to upload a new build just to change the icon that has nothing to do with app itself is silly. Tnx anyway

Comment: It kinda does sound silly but when You look at it, just include the new icon in Your next version of the app. No problem ;)

Comment: This really sucks. Especially since Apple takes a week or two to review an app :( Good answer nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: This is simply not true, I just changed it following the steps posted by Etienne678 below

Comment: Re comment above mine: I am unable to change it using the method found below by Etienne678.

Comment: User ratina below has posted what is now the correct answer to this question.

Comment: @ValKalinic, how can we add 1024x1024 (artwork icon) for iTunes applications now days?

Comment: I can not replace the large app icon. Status is waiting for review, I can delete the existing icon, but the link to upload another one is missing. Although the status was waiting for submission, the situation is the same. Once delete the existing app icon, the link to upload another one is missing!

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Hi,

I think, no need to upload a new build.
Sorry, it's in French, but I think you get it. You need to scroll a little bit but there you can upload an image file. Best is PNG and size 1024x1024.

Comment: This is the current way to do it as of 10/10/15

Comment: Note that you can't change this icon when the app is "Ready for Sale". As of this comment, create a new app version and hover your mouse cursor over the app icon; a little red minus icon will appear. If you're like me and don't see the minus icon, move your cursor around the upper left of the app icon image until your cursor changes and you can click on it, which deletes the icon and shows an option to upload a new one.

Answer (score 15):

**Change iTunes / App Store Icon.**

**Now**

With new UI & Functional changes in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/. Now your app icon will get change only with Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon -> ItunesArtwork@2x.png of 1024 X 1024.

**Earlier**

In earlier https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ UI & Functional there were separate features to change the App icon for iTunes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so you won't be able to change/add a new icon from app store connect right?

Comment: Yes correct. Only from Appicon xcasset is doable now.

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate. thank you for your time dude!

Answer (score 12):

I found out that you can change the large app icon if your app is not on sale yet -  but the place to change it is well hidden.

1.click on the app in itunes connect
2.click on "view details"
3.click on "edit" button next to Version Information at the top of the page
4.scroll all the way down
5.change icon

Comment: This appears to no longer be the case

Comment: Well you can do this, but only when you are updating your App and it is in the Waiting for Upload state, but once you upload this tends to be locked

Comment: It may not be apparent how to change the icon, because there are no "Edit" or "Choose File" links next to it. You just have to roll over the icon until you see a red circle with a white dash through it in the upper-left corner. Click on it to remove the icon, then it will be replaced with a "Choose File" link.

Comment: @Etienne678, i guess this answer is outdated now as i can't see any such option on itunes connect (my app is not on sale yet but i'm using test flight for interim builds). Kindly guide me how to add 1024x1024 icon. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was confused, because I used to know the "upload icon" field from my iOS app, but did not see the field when I wanted to submit my Mac OS X desktop app.

The answer above indicates that you can upload an icon only for updates, which is true for **iOS apps**, but for **Mac OS X apps**, you can *never* upload a separate icon file, instead the 512 icon is uploaded together with your binary bundle:

> "Note: You will not be asked to provide a large icon when adding your
>   Mac OS X app because it will be uploaded later as part of the binary."

from p56 of https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Comment: Invalid link - now for [iOS Developers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide)

Answer (score 5):

To change the icon from one app-version to the next, after adding the new version to prepare for submission:

- Delete the previous icon by clicking the red (-) on the icon
- Save changes
- Refresh page, and you can choose file to add

Comment: Thanks,Refresh help me.

Comment: no refresh needed anymore apparently. using Safari though

Comment: This is no longer the case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62710796/3398839).

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the build from build section, app icons automatically unlocked then you can update Appstore icon.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but after we delete the icon the link "Choose file" appears to be hidden, but if we save and then reload the page it shows up.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** Upload app with new App icon it will automatically update Appicon on App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I had to select a build in the "App Store" tab in App Store Connect before my app icon appeared in App Store Connect. Until I did that there was no icon displayed in TestFlight. You don't need to submit the build, just select one and that App Store Connect should pull the icon out of the build. It only took a few seconds for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also an issue I had was that the app was rejected and we wanted to update the icon before pushing a new version. In order to change the icon I had to remove the current build and then we could update the App Store Icon.