# Select a frequency/intensity level for each Apple content description iTunes Connect error

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my one app in `Apple Store`, its live. Now i need to send `metadata` for the new version of the same app. But before uploading new binary for second version, i need to change `large app icon (1024x1024)`. Currently my new version app status is "Prepare for Upload" and first version app status is "Ready for sale" on iTunes connect. Now after clicking on edit option in Version Information section. I have changed the app large logo successfully..but when i am clicking on save button then its not saving properly, and i am getting below error :

```
 Select a frequency/intensity level for each Apple content description.
```

[image]

I have checked this link also : [How do you change the app store's large icon on iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283126/how-do-you-change-the-app-stores-large-icon-on-itunes-connect)

I think this error related to Ratings, i have given all the ratings of Apple content description as None (Total 4+ Ratings). Please help me to solve this error. I have attached screenshot for reference.. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The alert indicates you have not filled all the **Rating** - **Apple Content Descriptions** which is below in your screenshot.

Let's go quick to the answer you need and then to the explanation. When you update your app, you have to check some checkboxes that are not by default:

[image]

As you can see in the image, my app has three rating fields that are empty: *Medical / Treatment information*, *Unrestricted Web Access* and *Gambling and Contests*.

You should **check those** for your app.

Now for the longer explanation:

In the case that you have filled all data, then I recommend to switch to another Internet browser, since it could also be a problem with processing the data you are submitting.

By the way, Apple changed the section. You may have received an e-mail:

> There have been several recent changes that may impact the content rating of your apps. These changes give users more information about your apps and help ensure legal compliance.
>
> **New App Content Descriptions**
>
> You can now use the following descriptions: Medical/Treatment Information, Gambling and Contests, and Unrestricted Web Access (for apps that permit navigating and viewing web pages, for example with an embedded browser).
>
> **Update to Territory-Specific Restrictions Based on Rating**
>
> Territory-specific restrictions in the Korea, Brazil, United Arab Emirates, and Saudi Arabia App Stores have changed. You can see the current rating and territory restrictions for your apps in Manage Your Apps on iTunes Connect.
>
> **New Rating System for the Brazil App Store**

Comment: Thanks @Injuanj..actually i forgot to select unrestricted/gambling field with NO, now its submitted successfully to the Apple Store.

Comment: "In the case that you have filled all data, then I recommend to switch to another Internet browser, since it could also be a problem with processing the data you are submitting."  -- for some reason CHROME would not work with this page, and I continually got the error message.  Switched to Safari, made the same edits as before, and succesfully saved.

Comment: "The alert indicates you have not filled all the" Right, but creating a new version of the app doesn't require filling them out, so why should editing it require it?

Comment: "You may have received an e-mail:" Yes, it says "You can now use the following descriptions". It doesn't say, "you have to use". In fact, if you don't need to edit the version information, you don't need to use them.

Comment: It does require it because new items have been introduced that you must answer about. Apple uses the "You can now use..." but they mean "you must specify whether... or not". Ah, and submitting a new version of the app requires editing the metadata, since you **must** change the version number.

Answer (score 16):

If you couldn't find edit button for age rating like me in the app information page, It is in the preparing for submission page.

Comment: ohh ! saved my day !! I think thats happened when first submit of the app

Comment: Thanks! have been looking quite a while for this

Answer (score 10):

In case you had difficulty finding the ratings section in the new iTunes Connect:

In the new iTunes Connect (2014) under the versions tab, scroll down to **General App Information** where you will see a small section titled **Rating** with a blue button titled **edit**. Tapping this button will bring up the Ratings section where you must make sure all fields are check-boxed. See attached screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As described in the alert (Red text), make sure you have selected either of the options for all Content Descriptions.

Comment: Buy why do you need to select them just to change already-entered version information?

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the picture shows the options that have appeared after your last update are not selected by default. That's why you may end up with that problem, because there will be new unchecked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to General -> App Information -> General App Information -> Age Rating -> Edit