# Updating app icon and screenshots

Tags: iphone, icons, version, screenshot

If I update my iPhone's app icon and screenshots will I have to release a new version? I want to keep my reviews for my app while updating these and possibly a new title. And would it be the same if I updated the category it was in?

Comment: It would be better to update the question (using the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30765208/edit)) instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about screenshots, but once the App is for sale the editing of icon is locked until next update. This post may help you [How do you change the app store's large icon on iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283126/how-do-you-change-the-app-stores-large-icon-on-itunes-connect)