# app icon not changed when upload app with new version in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have already one app in app store now, I want to upload new version of app with new app name and app icon to new version , so that I change app name and app icon to iTunes connect but after submit for review It display old app icon.

please help me.

Comment: Nothing to be worried about, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7283126/3339346

Answer (score 0):

The app icon you can upload to [iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) is only for the store display:

> The large app icon is displayed for your app **on the App Store** and, if
>   needed, is used to feature your app on the App Store.

If you want to have your app on the device home screen have a different icon, you need to update the icons in the binary/source code.